# add object to list when made

Tags: java, object, arraylist, type-mismatch

How do I add a setting to a list while making it?

So for a program I am making I want to add a Object to a list without calling a function.
So i have

```
    public static ArrayList<Setting> settings = new ArrayList<Setting>();
```

and now when I want to add something I would call

```
    private final Setting<Boolean> shouldDisplay = settings.add(new Setting("Description", false));
```

The only problem is that this gives me an error

**Type mismatch: cannot convert from boolean to Setting**

I know this is possible because I've seen code like

```
    private final Setting<Boolean> maintainLevel = sgGeneral.add(new BoolSetting.Builder()
            .name("maintain-level")
            .description("Maintains your current Y level when holding the jump key.")
            .defaultValue(false)
            .build()
    );
```

at https://github.com/MeteorDevelopment/meteor-client/blob/533fdb86ed812c76851dfcb57a1a24157fa04a59/src/main/java/meteordevelopment/meteorclient/systems/modules/movement/AirJump.java

How would I go about making it return a type Setting instead of boolean. Thanks

Comment: You can't change the return type of `List.add()`. `sgGeneral` in your example is probably a custom class.

Comment: `sgGeneral` is a `SettingGroup`. Perhaps you can use an instance of that?

Comment: Wouldn't it need to be `new Setting<Boolean>("Description", false)` to conform to the generic constants of the `ArrayList`?

Answer (score 0):

Your sequencing is wrong.  The `add` returns a boolean, not a Setting.

```
private final Setting<Boolean> shouldDisplay = 
    settings.add(new Setting("Description", false));
```

You want

```
private final Setting<Boolean> shouldDisplay = 
    new Setting("Description", false);
settings.add(shouldDisplay);
```

If you want 'add' to return a Setting then 'settings' has to be something other than the standard ArrayList.  Define your own class, and 'add' can return whatever you want.

Comment: That's the working code which is using a SettingGroup. The code that the OP is having problems with is earlier in the question.

Comment: Oh, I misread it. Hold on...